# How to Update nested objects in Elasticsearch documents?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to find the best practice to update a document with nested objects:
I am using the ES as a view cache:

let say I have tow entities in my SQL DB:
the First one is **Address** and the **Homes** and the relation between them is one too many

`Address Table has columns=> Id , Street, ZipCode`

`Home Table has colmns=> Id, AddressId(FK), price`

And I store them in ES aggregated:

```
Home : {
Id: 1,
price : 3000,
Address :{
   id: 1,
   street: "blabla",
   zibcode : 12345

  }
}
```

if I made any change on Address I want to update all **Home Documents** that contains the same Address in the Home index with the new value.
What I need to know how can I update all Documents in the same index in one request to ES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`_update_by_query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) is probably what you're after.

This ain't pretty but it should do the job:

```
PUT test/_doc/1
{
  "Id": 1,
  "price": 3000,
  "Address": {
    "id": 1,
    "street": "blabla",
    "zipcode": 12345
  }
}

POST test/_update_by_query
{
  "query": { 
    "term": {
      "Address.id": 1
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source['Address']['id'] = 2;ctx._source['Address']['street'] = 'foo';ctx._source['Address']['zipcode'] = 5678"
  }
}

GET test/_doc/1
```

And the output then is:

```
{
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 9,
  "_seq_no" : 8,
  "_primary_term" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "Address" : {
      "zipcode" : 5678,
      "street" : "foo",
      "id" : 2
    },
    "price" : 3000,
    "Id" : 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I Update The `Address` directly without iterating the props?

Comment: I don't know how you could define the full subdocument rather than overwriting each individual property — I tried it, but couldn't get it to work I'm afraid.